# I have the error "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO)"

Tags: php

This is my code:

```
<?php
include 'connect.php';
?>

<?php
$player=$_POST['player'];
$password=$_POST['password'];
$pass2=$_POST['pass2'];
$player=strip_tags($player);
$email=$_POST['email'];
$email=strip_tags($email);

if ($email == "")
(
echo "No has puesto la contraseña<br>";
echo " <A href='register.php'>Go back</a>";
exit;
```

I am getting this error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO) in C:\wamp\www\game\reguser.php on line 15

I tried to add ";" after `if ($email == "")` but nothing changes. I've changed brackets all over and am now out of ideas.

Comment: `if(some condition){ your code }`

Comment: Yup, you need curly brackets, not round ones. The error is easy to make when reading code with certain fonts - at small sizes, the characters can look quite similar!

Answer (score 3):

After the `if` clause, use braces `{` to introduce the code block and not `(`

```
if ($email == "")
{
    echo "No has puesto la contraseña<br>";
    echo " <a href='register.php'>Go back</a>";
    exit;
}
```

Comment: I've swapped the `<A>` for `<a>` - so the OP knows that HTML should generally be rendered in lower-case.

Comment: Alright. Didn't pay attention for that, cause the HTML code is not related to the question. Haven't even seen the upper case `A`. But you're totally right, it should be lower-cased.

Comment: Yep, we often like to point out other things here too - so in a database syntax error, we'll often point out a better library or a SQL injection vuln.

Answer (score 1):

The `if` statement in PHP needs `{ }` brackets, not `( )`. So your code is

```
if ($email == ""){
  echo "No has puesto la contraseña<br>";
  echo " <a href='register.php'>Go back</a>";
  exit;
}
```